# Docker: build using git push instead of ADD . /myapp

Tags: git, docker

Basically my Dockerfile looks like so:

```
FROM ruby:2.1.4
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
ADD Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
RUN bundle install
ADD . /myapp
```

It is fine, but the last line `ADD . /myapp` is not very smart: it duplicates every local files, including `<APP_ROOT>/log` which contains 8GB of useless data.

On the other hand, git is perfectly configured to store only usefull data (thanks to `.gitignore` among other).

Ain't there a simple solution to make a `git pull <local_files> master` from the Docker to the host or something?

Otherwise I could also pull from github but it adds external dependency.

Comment: Why not a RUN git pull <local_files> master instead of the ADD line? With RUN you have a shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you might be looking for the [.dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) file. Doing a `git pull` inside the image at build time doesn't seem like a very deterministic solution.

Comment: What I did is adding to my Dockerfile `ADD .gitignore .dockerignore` before `ADD . .`

Answer (score 0):

You could add git inside the docker image with

```
apt-get install -y git
```

Then a

```
RUN git clone ....
```

But, IMHO, I think it's best to clean your app folder and then add it via the ADD docker command